# How to choose orientation based on device on a Cocos2d V3 universal app

Tags: xcode, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I am Using Xcode 5.1 and Cocos2D V3.0.0.rc.3.

I have an universal app made with Cocos2d 2.0, it had a feature in AppDelegate.m that allowed to choose device orientation based on the device it was running before showing the intro scene:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
    return YES;
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
    return YES;
}

return NO;}
```

so if it was running on an iPhone, i fixed orientation to portrait mode, and if it was running on an iPad i fixed orientation to Landscape (Left), this way i loaded up a different background image for each device and later on a different scene for each device.

The thing is that i have not been able to use the same method in the newest version of Cocos2d, and i can not change it on the fly , otherwise with an if statement it would have been a piece of cake, and i can not also use an if statement in the Cocos2d config files (CCAppDelegate.h and .m)

Using the config provided by Xcode, is not working also, i think it is being overridden by Cocos2d at some point that i just can not figure out.

so, Anyone know how to choose orientation based on device? please note that it will be a fixed orientation and it is for the last Cocos2d version.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have managed it myself, by modifying CCAppDelegate.m, it allowed an if comparison, note that commented code was Cocos2d default code:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
    }



//    if ([_screenOrientation isEqual:CCScreenOrientationLandscape])
//    {
//        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
//    }


}
```

Thanks!